# Can Material Design be used natively with React Native on pre-Lollipop?

Tags: android, react-native, material-design, android-appcompat

The standard components that React Native offers are MD-styled only for Android Lollipop and greater.

Some developers who build apps with native code have told me about the AppCompat Android library that can be used to bring Material Design to pre-Lollipop Android devices. But that means you have to edit the XML markup, which is (if not impossible) not a way to go for React Native, as far as I'm concerned.

So can AppCompat be somehow used to create MD components? Perhaps a native module that's imported from JS and used in the application, or some other way

Keep in mind that I want my application to only support Android 4.1+ (no other platforms)

Comment: *Keep in mind that I want my application to only support Android 4.1+ (no other platforms)* then why don't you go native? Flame war start: react native on android platform is for.... Use Java/Kotlin

Comment: @Selvin because I'm generally experienced with JS development and I've always found Java to be very unwieldy and awkward. I know Kotlin is better on that part, but I just like the development speed of React Native